# solve a differential equation

Tags: self-study, differential-equations

I need to solve this differential equation where $F(x)$ is the distribution of $x$, with pdf $f(x)$:

$$F(x) = 1 - x \cdot f(x) $$

Comment: is this homework?  What motivates you? why is this stats related?

Comment: Add self study tag.

Comment: If this is an exercise question, you need to explain your attempts on the problem (just adding the self-study tag is not enough).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ are differentiable everywhere, this would lead to:

$$f(x)=-f(x)-xf'(x) \Rightarrow f'(x)/f(x) = -2/x.$$

This is separable, and yields solution $f(x)=cx^{-2}$. You now need to specify a domain for $f(x)$, which will determine $c$ . However,  since $0\leq F(x)\leq 1$, and $F(x)$ must be monotonically increasing, you need to be careful. $F(0)=1$ and $x$ cannot be negative (well, $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$). Since $xf(x)\geq 0$, and $F$ must be monotonically increasing, this implies that $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$. Thus $F(x)$ must correspond to a random variable $X=0$, which means that $f(x)$ must be a delta-function density. But that's also impossible if we require $F(x)$ to be differentiable at 0.

So there's no reasonable solution to the above equation.

Comment: Notice that the solution is impossible for a distribution since the density can never be negative and the distribution function F approaches 1 as x tends to infinity and is monotonically non-decreasing. While a solution can exist for a function F and its derivative f it does not apply to probability distributions.

Comment: @MichaelChernick why should $f(x)$ be negative? Assume that $x \in [0, +\infty)$, if $f(x)$ is negative then the RHS is greater than 1. right?

Comment: Look at the original equation F(x) = 1-x f(x).  F(x)=1 for x=0  and decreases as x increases from 0.  Then F is decreasing.  This is not a property of a distribution function.  In Alex Rs edited answer he does not account for F being monotonically non-decreasing. So even if you can make f positive in its domain I don't think you can make F monotonic non-decreasing.

Comment: The approach is correct, but the comments at the end are not.  For instance, $f(x) = 1/x^2 \mathbb{I}_{x\le -1}$ is one solution with the domain $x \lt -1$.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Sorry I must have been editing while you wrote this. There's definitely no reasonable solution to the above.

Comment: @whuber: if $x<-1$ then $F(x)>1$ for $x<-1$.

Comment: @whuber: What I meant is, your proposed solution would give $F(-2)=1-(-2/4)=3/2$, which clearly cannot be true.

Comment: I see what's going on: the problem is the additive constant of $1$. (+1)  Thank you for your patience.  What would help to make this perfectly clear is to state $F(x) = 1 - x f(x) = 1 - c/x$, and then the rest of your arguments would be evident even to us slower thinkers :-)

Comment: @AlexR. +1 for your twice edited answer.  I can now agree with it.